# How to divide a set into two subsets such that difference between the sum of numbers in two sets is minimal, where total sum of elements is large?

Tags: arrays

The question is similar to dividing set into 2 parts with minimum sum difference but here total sum of elements is very large (in range of integer but maybe larger than range of array). Also here maximum number of elements can be 62. Set is already sorted. Also we have to print the 2 subsets, if multiple answer exist then print one of them.

Approaches I tried:

1. Recursive (brute force): In this I made 2 recursive calls, one in which current element is included and another in which current element is not included. But this is taking too much time when number of elements are greater than 30. To prevent extra calls I exited the recursive function when minimum difference becomes 0, but it doesn't work as min diff will not always be 0.
2. Greedy: Started from largest element and added elements if current sum plus current element is less than half of total sum. It was fast but unfortunately gave wrong solutions.
3. Dynamic Programming: I tried this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-a-set-into-two-subsets-such-that-the-difference-of-subset-sums-is-minimum but here in DP time complexity O(n*totalSum) but in my case totalSum is large. Also it only prints the difference but we have to print both subsets also.